# Performance difference between selecting from table variable and from original table

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2016

Let's say I have an `Account` table and several other tables which reference `Account`.

Is there actually a performance difference between:

```
DECLARE @accountIDs table (id int);

INSERT INTO @accountIDs 
    SELECT id 
    FROM Account

DELETE TableA 
WHERE accountFk IN (SELECT id FROM @accountIDs)
```

and

```
DELETE TableA  
WHERE accountFk IN (SELECT id FROM Account)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with any question about performance, you should test the two methods.

In both cases, the performance is likely to be dominated by the deletion, not the finding of the records.  The one advantage of a table variable/temporary table is that the statistics are more accurate when it is created.

The queries that you have provided suggest that you would want two separate indexes on `(id)` and on `(accountFk)`.  With those indexes, I see little advantage to using a temporary table.

Answer (score 2):

Sure!

The declared table variable needs quite some overhead to be created and filled and there won't be any indexes (following your sample code). You could create your declared table with an index (Thx Gordon for your hint!), but this would just add even more overhead...

The id in your table `Account` will be indexed (probably / hopefully). The direct access will be much faster - for sure!

Furthermore you need a procedural approach to perform the first. Declaring a table valued variable will not be allowed in views or inline TVF.

Comment: Since SQL Server 2014, table variables have supported indexes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, yes, but creating this index will just add even more overhead, won't it?